# How to Fix Attribute Error: module 'graph' has no attribute 'get_user_token'

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have imported graph already, any idea why it can't identify the attribute?

```py
def display_access_token(graph: Graph):
    token = graph.get_user_token()
    print('User token:', token, '\n')

if user_input == '0':
    display_access_token(graph)
```

I am not sure what to do to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `graph` is supposed to be a `Graph` object (whatever that is), not a module.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred the sample code from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3). After reproducing from my end, this was working fine after adding `get_user_token()` in the graph.py. Below is the complete code in my graph.py.

```
import json
from configparser import SectionProxy
from azure.identity import DeviceCodeCredential, ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

class Graph:
    settings: SectionProxy
    device_code_credential: DeviceCodeCredential
    user_client: GraphClient
    client_credential: ClientSecretCredential
    app_client: GraphClient

    def __init__(self, config: SectionProxy):
        self.settings = config
        client_id = self.settings['clientId']
        tenant_id = self.settings['authTenant']
        graph_scopes = self.settings['graphUserScopes'].split(' ')

        self.device_code_credential = DeviceCodeCredential(client_id, tenant_id = tenant_id)
        self.user_client = GraphClient(credential=self.device_code_credential, scopes=graph_scopes)
        
    def get_user_token(self):
        a="Return from get_user_token"
        return a
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the issue is I need it to print out the website and the auth code similar to the documentation. Do you think there is a way to make that happen?

Comment: @Danny, Since your primary question is to identify the graph attribute, I have taken a sample code from the official document and provided the answer for the same. However, you can raise a new question regarding your current ask.